# How to find arc that connects two segments?

Tags: math, 2d

I will start with img that help me discribe my problem:
[image]

I have two connected segments AB & BC (and i know coords). How can I calculate arc between first and last green point. First & last green point is located with specified distance from B point (black segment). **I want to have all coords of green points in array.** Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: are first and last point the tangent points?

Comment: @AliAmiri yes they are

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's about math, and should be asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please describe _exactly_ what you have. How are the line segments parametrized and are they constrained to be tangent to a circle. Is this just a routine finding the rounding of a corner _B_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem boils down to finding the center of the circle *K* given a radius *r*, the point *B* and the directions *BC* and *BA*.

[image: pic]

Follow these steps:

1. Find angle *φ* between *BC* and *AB* using any "angle between two planar vectors" algorithm you find (there are many ways).
2. Calculate the arc inclusive angle *ψ* with

   `ψ = 2*arcsin(cot(φ/2))`
3. Calculate the distance *s* along *BC* where the arc ends

   `s = r*cot(φ/2)`
4. If the direction of *BC* is `e_BC=(ex,ey)` and the normal is `n_BC=(ey,-ex)` then the end of the arc *M* is

   `(mx,my) = (bx,by) + s*(ex,ey)`
5. And the circle center is

   `(kx,ky) = (mx,my) + r*(-ey,ex)`
6. Now take *N*=4 angle increments to rotate point *M* about *K* to get your green points

   `i-th point: i=1..4`

   `gx = kx + (mx-kx)*cos((i/4)*ψ)+(my-ky)*sin((i/4)*ψ)`

   `gy = ky - (mx-kx)*sin((i/4)*ψ)+(my-ky)*cos((i/4)*ψ)`

---

Based on other answers on this site on the TTR algorithm (tan-tan-radius), the best way to approach this problem is to offset the lines by the radius **r** and find the intersection which becomes the center of the arc.

[image: fig2]

Notice that there are *four* possible intersection points depending on which side of the line the offset is done. All are valid, and the user much choose/decide which one is wanted.

Comment: Is step 5 supposed to be `(kx,ky) = (mx,my) + r*(mx,my)`?

Comment: @ChanceSnow - no, but what I wrote wasn't right either. I think I fixed it with the latest [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28030228/revisions)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the second step? I could not find this equation anywhere else.

Comment: @Mat - take the height from **M** on the _KMB_ triangle. You end up with two similar triangles that have `sin(ψ/2) = cot(φ/2)`

Answer (score 1):

I changed your shape a little :

[image]

**Fact:** because Ta and Tc are tangents so OT<sub>a</sub>A and OT<sub>c</sub>C are perpendiculars and O is the center of the cycle.

from the above fact, we could find out that not for every two pairs of Ta and Tc there exist such a cycle, but if this exist OT<sub>a</sub> = OT<sub>c</sub>. so All you need to do is find O. after finding O you have the R and O (Ray and center) of a cycle so you could find every coordinate in its surface.

Comment: Ehhh I dont get it. Still trying to figure it out - maybe someone can help me. I have tangent points, circle center, also radius. The problem is that ABC can have different angles and coords. How can i start drawing points from Ta to Tc? To "divide" current arc I am using something like: `double angle = ((degree * i / divider) * Math.PI / 180.0)` and it works but how to start from specific angle (from Ta point)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your goal is with this eventually, but it looks to me that you basically want to make the "corner" B round.

Sure enough a circle is round. You are not asking for the circle but points on the circle.
I have the feeling that you will eventually connect these points with straight lines to approximate a circle. Apparently 5 points are sufficient for your desired "roundness" of the corner.

If that's true and you only approximate a circle in order to make the corner round, a bezier curve could also be interesting for you.
A [quadratic bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves) connects two points in a round-ish fashion by interpolating via a third anchor point. In your case B would be that anchor point. A disadvantage of this curve is that it's simply not a circle and will look different, but nonetheless produce a round shape.
Advantages are:
A lot of languages have built-in functions to draw these curves.
Some edge cases are handled better, for example if all three points are on one line, are identical, etc. With the circle solution, you have to take care of these cases on your own.

> How can i start drawing points from Ta to Tc?

To get interpolated points on an arc (given the center of the arc, first and last point) use slerp:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

Comment: Yes @null I want to make corner B round. Unfortunately I can't use bezier curves because I need extra control directly on points etc.

Comment: @user3688059 what exactly do you mean with "extra control"? You can distribute 5 points on this curve just like you do with the arc. It's actually easier because the whole algorithm is based on interpolation. In the link I provided, the interpolation parameter is named t, set t to 0 , 0.2 , 0.4, 0.6 , 0.8 , 1 to get 5 points distributed on the curve. I also added information on how to get those points on an arc to my answer, given you have the center point and the first and last point, it's called a slerp.